# Many kibana indexes

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, kibana-7

I'm trying figure out how backup kibana config.

My first aproach is make a dump of kibana index but...

I don't have a .kibana index. Instead I have..

- .kibana_1
- .kibana_2
- .kibana_task_manager_1

Besides, although I can't see any index called .kibana, If I ask to elasticsearch for a index called like this, I get it.

With GET /_cat/aliases I see .kibana is a alias of .kibana_2

Why is that?
(Is it because the upgrades?)

What are this indexes?
( Same than above)

Can I consolidate these indexes in one .kibana?

Proposal:

1. delete .kibana alias
2. reindex .kibana_2 to .kibana
3. delete .kibana_1 (since I think is not in use)
4. delete .kibana_task_manager alias
5. reindex .kibana_task_manager_1 to .kibana_task_manager

I'm running a cluster with elasticsearch + kibana 7.6.1 that has been upgraded from 6.6.8 <- 6.6.0 <- 5.4.x <- 2.2.0

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Those `.kibana_<id>` indexes are due to upgrades indeed. The index to which the `.kibana` alias points to is the current index. All the other ones can be safely deleted (except `.kibana_task_manager` of course) unless you might downgrade to a previous version.

If you want to back up your kibana data, you can simply snapshot and restore the `.kibana` indices.

If you want to know exactly why Kibana does this and how it does it, you can [read this troubleshooting guide](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/upgrade-migrations.html).

The bottom line is that you should not delete the `.kibana` alias and let Kibana do its job, because you will certainly undergo another migration to 7 soon.

Comment: Why .kibana* and not just .kibana? This alias sould have alll what I want no?

Comment: Yes, sorry, bad copy/paste. If you backup the `.kibana` alias, you'll end up backing up the index that the alias point to and that's sufficient. Unless of course you want to keep historical data if you want to restore your Kibana index on older versions.